# SchuWeb Sitemap error: non-numeric value encountered

Tags: component, multi-sites

I'm trying [Schuweb Sitemap (3.1)](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/schuweb-sitemap/) on two Joomla sites (3.9.21).

I'm getting the same error on both sites:

> Erreur d’analyse XML : données incompréhensibles après l’élément de document

> Emplacement : https://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_schuweb_sitemap&view=xml&tmpl=component&id=1
> Numéro de ligne 2, Colonne 1 :
> **Warning**:  A non-numeric value encountered in **/home/example/public_html/components/com_schuweb_sitemap/views/xml/tmpl/default.php** on line **27**

Comment: Welcome to JSE, Gareth.  Please always translate all non-English to English when posting.  Please take our [tour].  Volunteers that do not have that component may need to see what content is in that `default.php` file and what the fouling values are.  Please try to isolate and present the troublesome portion of code.

Comment: This question links to a NSFW and non-Joomla website. It might be better to change "xxx" to "example" if the author is trying to use "xxx" in the sense of an example.

Comment: Dear community, let's give the benefit of the doubt here.  I believe this was an innocent, poor choice in domain obfuscation.   In the future, please [anyone] just edit the question.  For reference: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255166/2943403

Comment: @Gareth please edit your question to translate all non-English to English.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak french, but I suppose this was a warning which leaded on some server settings to an error. This one is fixed with the 3.2.0
https://extensions.schultschik.com/products/schuweb-sitemap/schuweb-sitemap-3-2-0

Sorry for the late response, I overseen this question.